# Calling scp invokes sftp

Tags: terminal

Hi guys when I try to call scp from terminal emulator it invokes sftp, I have scp installed (along with ssh and sftp) in /system/bin folder.I know it's working correctly because typing just scp gives me the usage info but calling

> scp file user@ip:target

Gives the error sftp: illegal option - -x

Please help!

Comment: What is the exact command (with options) that you're trying to execute? The error suggests you're passing a `-x` option, and I've never seen an implementation of `scp` that had such an option. If you're not passing that in explicitly, then perhaps the file name is causing problems.

Comment: It's from a script to test if it's working code is 
touch testssh.txt

scp testssh.txt root@192.168.1.103:/home/testssh.txt
echo done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is caused because the "terminal emulator" app does not handle scp transfer (as far as im aware) upgrade to "better terminal emulator pro" app and the issue disappears.